# How to append an element to the end of a linked list?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, append, element

I've tried searching for the answers, but I can't seem to find anything to match mine. I'm doing a template linked list for school, and I'm getting a world of errors. But I only want help with one at the moment. I'm supposed to append an element to the end of a linked list, but we get:

```
append(ListNode)
```

At first, I thought: "Okay, create a new node, and insert at back..." but I read it over, and I have another function I have to make where I concatenate two linked lists together. So I think I have to append the linked list with an already made element. That way when I do the concat, I can use my append to attach the two. Or at least...this is just me thinking..

So at first, I did:

```
template<typename NODETYPE> 
bool List<NODETYPE>::append(NODETYPE &value)
{
    ListNode<NODETYPE> *newPtr = getNewNode(value); //creates new node

    if(isEmpty()) //checks if list is empty
    {
        firstPtr = lastPtr = newPtr;
        return true;
    }
    else //inserts new node at end of list
    {
        ListNode<NODETYPE> *tempPtr = lastPtr;

        tempPtr->nextPtr=newPtr;
        lastPtr = newPtr;
        return true;
    }
}
```

But since this only appends with a new node, I can't use it. Is there a way to attach a node already made? for example: attaching another linked list to the previous one?

My concat (unlike others I've searched) only uses one linked list. The previous linked list object calls the function, and then attaches a list

```
concat(&List)
```

So I'm all confused. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to change the signature of your append method so that it is passed a `ListNode*` and it appends it no matter if it is a single node or a whole linked list. After that, your code should look like this:

```
template<typename NODETYPE> 
bool List<NODETYPE>::append(ListNode<NODETYPE>* newPtr)
{
    //ListNode<NODETYPE> *newPtr = getNewNode(value); //creates new node

    if(isEmpty()) //checks if list is empty
    {
        firstPtr = lastPtr = newPtr;
        return true;
    }
    else //inserts new node at end of list
    {
        ListNode<NODETYPE> *tempPtr = lastPtr;

        tempPtr->nextPtr=newPtr;
        lastPtr = newPtr;
        while(lastPtr->nextPtr != NULL)
            lastPtr = lastPtr->nextPtr;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have not compiled it so there may be some errors but you get the idea.

Comment: This is a silly question, but my brain is tired =[ How would I put that in prototype of the header? I put:

bool append(ListNode) and I get ListNode is not a type.. eh (and thank you!)

Comment: `ListNode` must be some class or structure defined somewhere. You need to `#include` that header file where this is defined.

Comment: Yes, it's included in my header. #include "ListNode.h" but it also says prototype does not match any in class 
And, I fixed that problem by changing my append(ListNode) to append(ListNode<NODETYPE>*) but now i get the error invalid conversion from 'int' to 'ListNode<int>*"

Comment: @Nelliel: My advice: Pick up a good C++ book and start learning. This will help you overcome these problems yourself in the long run. As for the issue you are facing right now, look at the place in code where this `append` method is called and see that you are passing an `int` there. Change it to `ListNode`

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to do that. I really need to get the hang of this. But yeah, thanks. Only problem is I can't change my main function because it's what my lecturer provided to test the code. If it doesn't run with his cpp then something is wrong with our code.

Comment: Then in that case you will have to write two separate functions. `concat` and `append`. You wont be able to do both things in one function because both of them will get called differently.

Answer (score 0):

The exact steps for concatenating lists in place depends on the particular implementation details. The simplest case is a singly linked list, in which case you just link the second head to the old tail. If you have a tail pointer, remember to update that. For a doubly linked list, you'll have to link the second head back to the old tail as well. And if you're using a sentinal node, remember to take care of that too.

Edit: Disregard this, I got confused and thought you might be trying to use the standard list.

In C++, `std::list` is a doubly linked list with sentinel node, which makes concatenation nontrivial. Furthermore, you're not supposed to mess with the internals anyway. If you want to use a standard container, you need to adhere to the public API for it, or else Bad Stuff will happen. Fortunately, I'm sure there's a library function for concatenation.

Comment: Well, I can't use a doubly linked list, or anything else from the library, because I don't think we've learnt anything really to help us with this yet. Everything is from scratch.

But still, the concatenate in the main looks something like this:

    Li.concat(Li2);

Li2 is also an object. Li and Li2 are both int. It's really the append getting to me though. I get something like:

       Li2.append(5);

I look at that, and I still think I have to create a new node to attach to the end. I think I've overworked my brain with the other functions...I'm getting confused with everything now ha

Answer (score 0):

For concatenating list2 to to say a list , list1 , you will have to attach the head of list2 to the last node of list1 and update lastPtr, something like this :

```
//apart from checking for basic sanity like empty list and things 
// suppose argument passed is ListNode list2
        ListNode<NODETYPE> *tempPtr = lastPtr;

        tempPtr->nextPtr=list2;
        tempPtr = list2;
        while(tempPtr->next != NULL) {
              tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
        }
         lastPtr = tempPtr;

        return true;
```

Comment: This will sound a bit silly, I kinda figured out that part already that you gave me, but thanks for confirming it for me -- but how do i set up the prototype for this? I've never referred to an object (Linked List inside of a linked list) before, and I've been trying to figure this out for days.  

I put
void List<NODETYPE>::concat(List) but I know that's wrong..Is there a special way to do that? Or how to refer to the different lists separately inside the code?

Comment: To set up the prototype, it should be like : bool List<NODETYPE>::concat(ListNode *list2) -  You just pass the pointer to the head of the linked list.

Comment: Thank you :D Um, how could I check if the second list is empty? I know I'm asking a lot --> I'm a bit frustrated with not knowing so much..

Comment: For that you just have to check in an if statement if list2==NULL.